# Display data in hyperlinks and link to another .php page

Tags: php, sql

Well I got this program that displays Staff ID's in hyperlinks in which the user can click on one and takes you to another php page called `task7.php`. This `task7.php` page is linked to an HTML page in which the user enters a staff id and various purchase details are displayed (this works fine).

What seems to be happening is that once the user clicks on a hyperlink the field names are showing up in the table but with no details of that staff id. I think the program i created is stuck into thinking that it can only get details for a staff id if it is entered into `task7.htm` and not through a hyperlink. What i want to know is how do i run the query which shows all purchase details through the hyper links without damaging the current code I've created to display the details through user input.

**NOTE**: When i click any hyperlinked staff id's not only do i just get the field names in a table, but i also recieve a error:

> Notice: Undefined index: staffID in I:\twa\twa291\task7.php.

Here's the hyperlink code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Prac 2 Task 3</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa291", ".....");
mysql_select_db("factory291", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );

$sql = "SELECT staffID, staffName FROM staff";

$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());


?>


<table border="1" summary="Staff Orders">
<tr>
<th>Staff ID</th>
<th>Staff Name</th>

</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>

<tr>

<td><a href="task7.php?staffno=<?php echo $row["staffID"]?>">
    <?php echo $row["staffID"]?></a><
<td><?php echo $row["staffName"]?></td>

</tr>


<?php   }
mysql_close($conn); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `task7.php` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Prac 2 Task 3</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa291", "......");
mysql_select_db("factory291", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );  ?>

<?php
$staffid= $_GET["staffID"];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT orderID, orderDate, orderDate, shippingDate, staffName FROM purchase, 
staff 
WHERE staff.staffID='$staffid'"; 


$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());

?>

<table border="1" summary="Staff Orders">
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Shipping Date</th>
<th>Staff Name</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>

<tr>

<td><?php echo $row["orderID"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["orderDate"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["shippingDate"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["staffName"]?></td>

</tr>


<?php   }
mysql_close($conn); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You create the url with the key `staffno`, then try and retrieve key `staffID`.

Change in task7.php:

```
$staffid= $_GET["staffno"]; // not $staffid= $_GET["staffID"];
```

OR change hyperlink code:

```
<td><a href="task7.php?staffID=<?php echo $row["staffID"]?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

in first page you pass "staffno" parameter but in  task7.php you get $_GET["staffID"];

so change like this:

```
<a href="task7.php?staffID=<?php echo $row["staffID"]?>">
```

i personally prefer use "staffID" than "staffno" so it's the same like column name in DB